# Update value of each item in JsonNode (jackson)

Tags: java, java-8, thymeleaf

```
JsonNode response = objectMapper.readTree(responseBody);
String textData = response.get("data").toString();
```

Below is the output of textData.

```
[{"acc":"1278915","for":"159000"},{"acc":"8963258","for":"152863"},{"acc":"9632578","for":"258963"}]
```

As you can see the comment in above code, the textData returns value to me like above. I want to do mask the above `acc` in that, How can I do this?

"acc" : "xx78915" , I want to replace first two digits from acc for each item.

I have use below but it doesn't do it.

```
String output = "xxxx" + textData.substring(4);
```

After that I return it to my view

```
return (List<Map<String, String>>) objectMapper.readValue(text, List.class);
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be treating it *as JSON* rather than just as a single string. Modify `response` instead of converting that to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `textData` represents valid json format, so either you can convert it into `List<Model>` or `List<Map<String,String>>` using [objectmapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html)

```
public class Model {
  private String acc;
  private String foo; 

  // getters and setters
  }
```

To model `List<Model>`

```
List<Model> list = objectMapper.readValue(jsonCarArray, new TypeReference<List<Model>>(){});
```

or to `List<Map<String,String>>

```
List<Map<String,String>> list = objectMapper.readValue(jsonCarArray, new TypeReference<List<Map<String,String>>>(){});
```

And then use [computeIfPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```
list.forEach(obj->obj.computeIfPresent("acc",(key,val)-> /*logic to modify value */));
```

Or another approach by iterating `JsonNode`

```
JsonNode response = objectMapper.readTree("responseBody");

    if(response.get("data").isArray()) {
        for (JsonNode node : response.get("data")){
            ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode)node;
            if(objectNode.hasNonNull("acc")){
                String val = objectNode.get("acc").asText();
                objectNode.put("acc","xx"+val.subString(2));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using returning like this to view 

`return (List<Map<String, String>>) objectMapper.readValue(text, List.class);` But before that I want to modify the value.

Comment: i have tried his answer it gives me error on .put() in his answer

Comment: you need type casting, check my updated answer @AsfandyarKhan

Comment: You need to import it from jackson, try to import @AsfandyarKhan

Comment: Ok No error on it now. is it possible to convert it back to string now objectNode.toString() ? how will i access it ?

Comment: You don't need any convesrtions, just print response.get("data") outside for loop, you will see the changes @AsfandyarKhan

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace the first two digits from acc for each item, try regex:

```
String output = textData.replaceAll("(\"acc\":\"[0-9]{2})", "\"acc\":\"xx");
```

Answer (score 0):

`response.get("data")` actually contains another JSON, a JSON-Array:

```
[
    {
       "acc":"1278915",
       "for":"159000"
    },
    {
       "acc":"8963258",
       "for":"152863"
    },
    {
       "acc":"9632578",
       "for":"258963"
    }
]
```

So to alter any objects from the array you need to iterate over the items like in any other array:

```
 JsonNode arrayNode = response.get("data");
 if (arrayNode.isArray()) {
     for (JsonNode objectNode : arrayNode) {  // objectNode is again a JSON (object)
         System.out.println(objectNode);   // this would print the object as string like: "{'acc':'912345','for':'123345'}"
         // so to alter that object you get the "acc" node
         // objectNode.get("acc")  -- this is the String "912345", but Strings are immutable so you need to set the new value in the objectNode again
         objectNode.put("acc", "xxxx" + objectNode.get("acc").toString().substring(4));  // it will put the new string value under the key "acc" in the json object
     }
 }
```

And if nothing goes wrong you `arrayNode` should look like this afterwards:

```
[
    {
       "acc":"xxxx915",
       "for":"159000"
    },
    {
       "acc":"xxxx258",
       "for":"152863"
    },
    {
       "acc":"xxxx578",
       "for":"258963"
    }
]
```

Comment: It gives me error at objectNode.put(), Java cannot find symbol

Comment: Sorry for that! `objectNode` is actually a `JsonNode`, which does not have that method `put`. But you can cast it: `((ObjectNode)objectNode).put("acc",  ..... )`

Comment: OK let me try this

Comment: I  write this from my head - so if this is not working I propose you refer to Deadpool's answer with the Models

Comment: Error:(424, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  location: variable objectNode of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode

Answer (score 0):

Example using  org.json library- maybe this will be useful for others

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray("[{\"acc\":\"1278915\",\"for\":\"159000\"},{\"acc\":\"8963258\",\"for\":\"152863\"},{\"acc\":\"9632578\",\"for\":\"258963\"}]");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(array.get(i).toString());
            String newStr = jsonObject.getString("acc").replace(jsonObject.getString("acc").substring(0, 2), "XX");
            jsonObject.put("acc", newStr);
            array.put(i, jsonObject);
        }
        System.out.println("Output array : " + array);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Output array : [{"acc":"XX78915","for":"159000"},{"acc":"XX63258","for":"152863"},{"acc":"XX32578","for":"258963"}]
```

Or

Using Java Regular expression

```
    public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String str =  "[{\"acc\":\"1278915\",\"for\":\"159000\"},{\"acc\":\"8963258\",\"for\":\"152863\"},{\"acc\":\"9632578\",\"for\":\"258963\"}]";
        String result = str.replaceAll("(\"acc\":\"[0-9]{2})", "\"acc\":\"xx");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[{"acc":"xx78915","for":"159000"},{"acc":"xx63258","for":"152863"},{"acc":"xx32578","for":"258963"}]
```

Comment: is it possible to do the last 3 digits?

Comment: Possible String newStr = (jsonObject.getString("acc").replace(jsonObject.getString("acc").substring(0, 2), "XX")).substring(0, jsonObject.getString("acc").length() - 3)+"XX";

Comment: **Note** Code optimization needed